# Printing an alphabet pyramid in PL/SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have an exercise to write a program which prints out an alphabet pyramid like this:

```
    A
   ABA
  ABCBA
 ABCDCBA
ABCDFDCBA
```

The task also suggests using INSTR, LPAD, UPPER.

I want to have the pyramid which contains the all the letters in the alphabet. However, I find it is easier to make it in numbers first so:

```
IF x in 0..25 loop
dbms_output.put_line(x);
end loop;
end;
```

The result is just a straight line of numbers from 0-25. I don't know how to add spaces before the numbers, which eventually needs to be letters, to form a the pyramid shape.
Please don't give the full answer, I just need some suggestions and diretions to solve this task.

Comment: Thanks @KaushikNayak. I did see this post and I still haven't understood how to make it in letters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way of doing this is to generate the base of the pyramid:

- `CHR(n)` will generate an ASCII character; and
- you can concatenate strings with `||` so `str := str || CHR(65)` will append an `A` to the end of the string.
- The [`FOR i IN [REVERSE] 1 .. repetitions LOOP`](https://docs.oracle.com/cloud/latest/db112/LNPLS/for_loop_statement.htm#LNPLS1536) statement can be used to loop through values.

If you can generate the base then the [`TRANSLATE` function](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions196.htm) can replace multiple characters with other characters in a 1-to-1 correspondence so:

- `TRANSLATE( 'ABC', 'ABC', '  A' )` outputs `'  A'`
- `TRANSLATE( 'ABC', 'ABC', ' AB' )` outputs `' AB'`
- `TRANSLATE( 'ABC', 'ABC', 'ABC' )` outputs `'ABC'`

If you have generated the base of the pyramid then you have a string where the sub-string starts with those characters and you just need sub-string of the appropriate length padded with spaces.

`DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( string )` will print a string to the console.

[Full Solution - DO NOT FOLLOW THE LINK IF YOU DON'T WANT TO KNOW HOW I DID THIS](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/64174/2)

Answer (score 4):

This one works:

```
DECLARE
    aLine VARCHAR2(100);
BEGIN
    FOR PyramidLevel IN 0..25 LOOP
        aLine := NULL;

        FOR i IN 0..PyramidLevel-1 LOOP
            aLine := aLine || CHR(i+65);
        END LOOP; 

        FOR i IN REVERSE 0..PyramidLevel LOOP
            aLine := aLine || CHR(i+65);
        END LOOP;
        aLine := LPAD(aLine, 26+PyramidLevel);       

       DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('_'||aLine);
    END LOOP;
END;


_                         A
_                        ABA
_                       ABCBA
_                      ABCDCBA
_                     ABCDEDCBA
_                    ABCDEFEDCBA
_                   ABCDEFGFEDCBA
_                  ABCDEFGHGFEDCBA
_                 ABCDEFGHIHGFEDCBA
_                ABCDEFGHIJIHGFEDCBA
_               ABCDEFGHIJKJIHGFEDCBA
_              ABCDEFGHIJKLKJIHGFEDCBA
_             ABCDEFGHIJKLMLKJIHGFEDCBA
_            ABCDEFGHIJKLMNMLKJIHGFEDCBA
_           ABCDEFGHIJKLMNONMLKJIHGFEDCBA
_          ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPONMLKJIHGFEDCBA
_         ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQPONMLKJIHGFEDCBA
_        ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRQPONMLKJIHGFEDCBA
_       ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSRQPONMLKJIHGFEDCBA
_      ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTSRQPONMLKJIHGFEDCBA
_     ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUTSRQPONMLKJIHGFEDCBA
_    ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVUTSRQPONMLKJIHGFEDCBA
_   ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWVUTSRQPONMLKJIHGFEDCBA
_  ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXWVUTSRQPONMLKJIHGFEDCBA
_ ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYXWVUTSRQPONMLKJIHGFEDCBA
_ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZYXWVUTSRQPONMLKJIHGFEDCBA
```

Looks like `DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE()` trims leading space characters (at least in my TOAD), so I put `_` at the beginning.

Comment: OP requested "Please don't give the full answer, I just need some suggestions and diretions to solve this task."

Comment: @MT0 you are right, I was too lazy in reading the question carefully.

Comment: @MT0 It's always good to have the solution provided because i have seen cases where OP again post the same question if (s)he get stuck somewhere.

Answer (score 4):

Pure SQL using model clause

```
select lpad(x1, 26, ' ') || substr(x2, 2) x from dual
model
dimension by (1 id)
measures (cast(null as varchar2(26)) x1, cast(null as varchar2(26)) x2)
(x1[for id from 1 to 26 increment 1] = x1[cv(id)-1] || chr(64+cv(id)),
x2[for id from 1 to 26 increment 1] = chr(64+cv(id)) || x2[cv(id)-1]);

X
---------------------------------------------------
                         A
                        ABA
                       ABCBA
                      ABCDCBA
                     ABCDEDCBA
                    ABCDEFEDCBA
                   ABCDEFGFEDCBA
                  ABCDEFGHGFEDCBA
                 ABCDEFGHIHGFEDCBA
                ABCDEFGHIJIHGFEDCBA
               ABCDEFGHIJKJIHGFEDCBA
              ABCDEFGHIJKLKJIHGFEDCBA
             ABCDEFGHIJKLMLKJIHGFEDCBA
            ABCDEFGHIJKLMNMLKJIHGFEDCBA
           ABCDEFGHIJKLMNONMLKJIHGFEDCBA
          ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPONMLKJIHGFEDCBA
         ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQPONMLKJIHGFEDCBA
        ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRQPONMLKJIHGFEDCBA
       ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSRQPONMLKJIHGFEDCBA
      ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTSRQPONMLKJIHGFEDCBA
     ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUTSRQPONMLKJIHGFEDCBA
    ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVUTSRQPONMLKJIHGFEDCBA
   ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWVUTSRQPONMLKJIHGFEDCBA
  ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXWVUTSRQPONMLKJIHGFEDCBA
 ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYXWVUTSRQPONMLKJIHGFEDCBA
ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZYXWVUTSRQPONMLKJIHGFEDCBA

26 rows selected.
```

Update. Just for fun, the same result with single rule

```
select lpad(' ', 26 - ceil(length(x)/2), ' ')  || x as x from dual
model
dimension by (1 id)
measures (cast(null as varchar2(51)) x)
(x[for id from 1 to 26 increment 1] = substr(x[cv(id)-1], 1, cv(id)-1) || chr(64+cv(id)) || substr(x[cv(id)-1], cv(id)-1));

select lpad(' ', 26 - ceil(length(x)/2), ' ')  || x as x
from (select 'A' x from dual union all select 'ABA' from dual)
model
dimension by (rownum id)
measures (cast(x as varchar2(51)) x)
(x[for id from 3 to 26 increment 1] = regexp_replace(x[cv(id)-1], '(.)(.)\1', '\1\2' || chr(64+cv(id)) || '\2\1'));
```

Answer (score 1):

Two suggestion:

In the first line there are 1 letter, in the second line 3 letters, in the third line 5 letters... so 1,3,5,7,9.... to the infinite. I cant understand what do you want with:

```
IF x in 0..25 loop
```

The break line character for your dbms_output is:

```
chr(13)||chr(10) -> Windows
chr(10) -> Unix
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it all in SQL.  This works in Toad (run as a script; F5).  Note I got an "invalid number" error unless I wrapped the "level-1" in a TO_NUMBER() call in the second regexp_substr call.

Hints: Use the CONNECT BY construct to loop through the rows.  CONNECT BY automatically makes available a variable called `level` that increments for each iteration.

Look for patterns.  How many rows are expected? How many spaces in front of the first letter for each row? What variables are available that you can manipulate in a calculation?  Other answers provide hints as well.

Did you notice the Fibonacci sequence?  The number of characters on each row is a sum of that row number plus the number of the preceding row (nothing to do with the answer (at least my answer), just a pattern I noticed).

[SQL fiddle example answer here, but leading spaces will not show.  You have to paste the solution into Toad or SQLPlus and uncomment the "set" lines.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/64174/9)

Edit: I went to SQL Fiddle to try something and found it was hanging.  As I didn't want my answer to be lost and everyone was posting full answers anyway, here it is for posterity:

```
SQL> set heading off;
SQL> set feedback off;
SQL> set pagesize 0;
SQL>
SQL> select lpad(' ', 26-level, ' ') ||
     regexp_substr('ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ', '(.{' || level ||'})', 1, 1, NULL, 1) ||
     reverse(regexp_substr('ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ', '(.{' || to_number(level-1) ||'})', 1, 1, NULL, 1)) pyramid
     from dual
     connect by level <= 26;

                         A
                        ABA
                       ABCBA
                      ABCDCBA
                     ABCDEDCBA
                    ABCDEFEDCBA
                   ABCDEFGFEDCBA
                  ABCDEFGHGFEDCBA
                 ABCDEFGHIHGFEDCBA
                ABCDEFGHIJIHGFEDCBA
               ABCDEFGHIJKJIHGFEDCBA
              ABCDEFGHIJKLKJIHGFEDCBA
             ABCDEFGHIJKLMLKJIHGFEDCBA
            ABCDEFGHIJKLMNMLKJIHGFEDCBA
           ABCDEFGHIJKLMNONMLKJIHGFEDCBA
          ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPONMLKJIHGFEDCBA
         ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQPONMLKJIHGFEDCBA
        ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRQPONMLKJIHGFEDCBA
       ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSRQPONMLKJIHGFEDCBA
      ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTSRQPONMLKJIHGFEDCBA
     ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUTSRQPONMLKJIHGFEDCBA
    ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVUTSRQPONMLKJIHGFEDCBA
   ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWVUTSRQPONMLKJIHGFEDCBA
  ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXWVUTSRQPONMLKJIHGFEDCBA
 ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYXWVUTSRQPONMLKJIHGFEDCBA
ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZYXWVUTSRQPONMLKJIHGFEDCBA
SQL>
```