# Printing the Sierpinski-Triangle

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g

The task asks to write the program, which prints the Sierpinski triangle.
The desired result looks like this:

```
#
##
# #
####
#   #
##  ##
# # # #
########
#       #
##      ##
# #     # #
####    ####
#   #   #   #
##  ##  ##  ##
# # # # # # # #
################
#               #
##              ##
# #             # #
####            ####
#   #           #   #
##  ##          ##  ##
# # # #         # # # #
########        ########
#       #       #       #
##      ##      ##      ##
# #     # #     # #     # #
####    ####    ####    ####
#   #   #   #   #   #   #   #
##  ##  ##  ##  ##  ##  ##  ##
# # # # # # # # # # # # # # # #
################################
```

This is what I tried:

```
declare
v_str varchar2(10) := '#';
n NUMBER := 4;
begin
   for i in 1..n loop
      v_str := rpad(v_str, i, '#');
      for l in 1..8 loop
      v_str := rpad(v_str, l, v_str);
      dbms_output.put_line(v_str);
      end loop;
   end loop;
end;
```

As you can see I didn't get the expected result, that I want. The problem is I don't know to make empty spaces within the triangles. My idea is to make a variable, which contains this:

```
#
##
# #
####
```

and then put it in 1..8 loop. And I have some troubles writing this down in code. Any suggestions/hints? Thanks!

Comment: You raised a similar question already here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46728915/printing-an-alphabet-pyramid-in-pl-sql - looks like you have quite a "special" teacher.... Does your teacher likes you to learn programming PL/SQL or algorithmic?

Comment: Hi @WernfriedDomscheit. My teacher is teaching me PL/SQL and database. Just started learning with him 2 weeks ago, but he gave lots of tough questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it using [this code](https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Category:Ada)

```
DECLARE
  n PLS_INTEGER := 4;
BEGIN
  FOR line IN REVERSE 0 .. POWER( 2, n ) - 1 LOOP
    FOR col IN 0 .. POWER( 2, n ) - 1 LOOP
      IF BITAND( line, col ) = 0 THEN
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT( '#' );
      ELSE
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT( ' ' );
      END IF;
    END LOOP;
    DBMS_OUTPUT.NEW_LINE;
  END LOOP;
END;
/
```

Comment: Strange. Different outputs in Toad and sql developer.

Comment: @KaushikNayak Copy/pasting the second loop, I had mistakenly not removed the `REVERSE` and it was outputting the triangle right-aligned (with leading whitespace). I believe that [in some versions Toad strips leading whitespace from DBMS_OUTPUT](https://www.toadworld.com/products/toad-for-oracle/toad_for_oracle_beta_program/f/86/t/25049) but SQL developer doesn't which will give you the difference. The corrected version (without the second `REVERSE`) should be identical in both (left-aligned) as it has no leading whitespace.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. Sorry to bother you again, but can you maybe explain the 4th and 5th line?

Comment: It is a loop from `0` to `2` raised to the power of `n` less `1` (so for `n=4` it is 0 .. 2^4-1 = 15) - the first loop decrements from higher to lower bound (i.e. in `REVERSE` order) and the second loop increments from lower to higher bound.